# Ships and consignments

Tags: algorithm

Suppose We own an export company and own infinite many ships with capacity C each. We are to ship n objects with wieghts w[1...n]. We want to use the least number of ships to ship all the objects. The objects the non fractional (you cant take them in parts). What sort of algorithm would we apply to get the minimum number of ships that we need to use to send all the n objects.

n is of the order 10^5

My Thoughts:

We definitely cannot go greedy. It can be the case that 2 of smaller ones of weights make the ship entirely full while if we pick the greatest weignt a lot of space is wasted.

Also we can see this as 0-1 knapsack problem, with sack capacity of C and value of each object is equal to its weight. 
We will have to apply 0-1 knapsack again and again for every ship which will be too slow.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks... that should get me started